# Conditionally formatting cells with arrow indicators doesn't work properly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to conditionally format a few cells to display either an up arrow or a down arrow if the cell's value is positive (1) or negative (-1) with the following:

```
|   A    |   B   |
| $10,000| $5,000|
|        |       |

= SIGN(B2 - A2)
```

Now for some odd reason the signs keep coming out with UP arrows when the value is actually negative. Any ideas on why this might be?

Comment: the formula you should returns a -1 as is expected for a negative value.  Could you share how you are using conditional formatting to display arrows.  If I go into the "more rules" under icon set you can set your cutoff values, maybe this is your issue?

Comment: It returns a negative number in the cell, but the arrow points up. I went to conditional formatting > icon sets > directional arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting conditional formatting you need to manage the rules so it knows what breakpoints to use for the up arrow, down arrow and side arrow.

Select your cell with conditional formatting goto the ribbon>Home>Conditional Formatting>Manage Rules

Make sure your icon set rule is selected (if there is multiple) and click edit rule.

In the bottom right you set when each arrow is used.  Top box do >0 number.  Second row put >=0 number.

This will have a green up arrow above 0, yellow side arrow at 0 and a red down arrow for negative.